# How can I inject a bean into an ApplicationContext before it loads from a file?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` and I would like the beans defined in the XML to take as a constructor argument a bean which is not declared in Spring

For example, I would like to do:

```
<bean class="some.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="myBean" />
</bean>
```

So I could imagine doing this via something like:

```
Object myBean = ...
context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(xmlFile);
context.addBean("myBean", myBean); //add myBean before processing
context.refresh();
```

Except that there is no such method :-( does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about programmatically creating an empty parent context first, registering your object as a singleton with that context's `BeanFactory` using the fact that `getBeanFactory` returns an implementation of `SingletonBeanRegistry`.

```
parentContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
parentContext.refresh(); //THIS IS REQUIRED
parentContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("myBean", myBean)
```

Then specify this context as a parent to your "real" context The beans in the child context will then be able to refer to the bean in the parent.

```
String[] fs = new String[] { "/path/to/myfile.xml" } 
appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(fs, parentContext);
```

Comment: I will check this and upvote you! (Just getting code to compile :-)

Comment: ApplicationContext does not implement SingletonBeanRegistry

Comment: I've played around following your suggestion with no luck. More help welcome!

Comment: I got there in the end; I've modified your answer to include working code. Cheers for the pointer and have an upvote!

Comment: Is there any additional configuration that needs to be setup in myfile.xml? (like the use of <import>? ) any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I had trouble solving this with an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, I found the following alternative:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
beanFactory.registerSingleton("customBean", new CustomBean());
context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(beanFactory);
context.register(ContextConfiguration.class);
context.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the existing context needs the bean you wish to inject then things need to be done a little differently. The approaches in other answers don't work for the following reasons

- Context cannot be refreshed until the missing bean is registered
- refresh() causes the injected bean to be destroyed.

This can be worked around by using a "bean factory post processor", this allows code to be run after the context is loaded but before it it refreshed.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
applicationContext.setConfigLocation("/org/example/app-context.xml");
applicationContext.getBeanFactoryPostProcessors().add(new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("customBeanName", customBean);
    }
});
applicationContext.refresh();
```