# How to pass an object into ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring.
How can we pass an object to an application context xml file?

For example:

I have class `A` which calls:

```
`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/storage.xml");
```

`storage.xml` has a bean (of class `B`) defined inside it.

I want to create object of class `B` from `A` and pass it via the `ApplicationContext`.

How can i do it?

Comment: check accepted answer on this quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109953/how-can-i-inject-a-bean-into-an-applicationcontext-before-it-loads-from-a-file?rq=1

Comment: A.ApplicationContext.getBean(name of b). your 'create' means 'get' do you?

Comment: Usually your application code (`A`, `B`) is unaware of Spring, so you would add a field of type `B` into `A` and annotate it `@Inject`. What type of application are you writing (webapp, standalone?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way. In class A

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/storage.xml");

B objB = (B) context.getBean("beanIDofB");

objB.someMehodOfB();
```

But this way of doing is outdated. Try spring annotation